# PostgreSQL identity/generated columns do not work with Append to Esri Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to set a column as an integer primary key separate from what Esri maintains. This is so it can exist in non-spatial tables and the features retain the key as they exist across other tables.

The problem is, if a field is set to Identity or Generated column, it does not allow direct inserts/updates to write to the field. I want these values populated at the time of appending to the layer via ArcGIS Pro.

The way the append tool works is it generates a prepared statement listing all the fields and all the values in the destination table -- even if they aren't referenced/mapped during the append. This prevents the load from working because it is trying to insert/update on the Identity field instead of letting it do its own thing.

I am looking at DB triggers to do this but it doesn't seem like a clean approach. I've also thought about running the incrementing integer field on the table in Pro but that only works on unregistered layers. Any ideas?

> STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO poi_gdb.poi.poi_raw (objectid, name,
> primary_category, secondary_category, osm_unique_id, shape, poi_id,
> processed_timestamp) VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5,  $6 , $7, $8)

Comment: You can't include the ID column in the INSERT  list. There's a bunch of ways to implement this, including appending to a view and letting the DEFAULT do its thing. I've even created a shadow table and pushed the INSERT across with a trigger. Without details on what you're doing, though, it's hard to fix anything.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. Yeah I know the issue is having the ID column referenced in the INSERT list. That's just how Esri's Append tool is structured behind the scenes. I don't think there's any way around that. I have a team that will likely be appending via the ArcGIS Pro UI so that's a route I need to account for.

Right now I am going with a trigger that checks IDs across a set of tables before iterating up from the max value to assign a new ID at the time of the Append. It is working but I doubt it's the most elegant solution. Would views allow the updating of a identity column?

Comment: Given that Append supports column mapping, you seem to be avoiding an easy solution. That sounds like a heinous trigger; a single sequence can do this job better than many. Note that Esri *doesn't* use sequences because of poor performance on bulk insert.

Comment: @Vince I've mapped columns via Append; the statement the Append tool makes behind the scenes remains the full prepared statement referencing all columns. See main post.

Comment: Try inserting to a view that doesn't include the custom ID column